# Add class if less than 0

Tags: jquery

How can I add a class to the `div#value` if the result is less than`0`?

I need to add two classes: one if the value is less than 0, another if it's greater than 0.

I tried everything I could so I'd be grateful for your help! 
Thanks in advance!

```js
$(function() {

  var valueElement = $('#value');

  function incrementValue(e) {
    valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment));
    return false;
  }

  $('#plus').bind('click', {
    increment: 1
  }, incrementValue);

  $('#minus').bind('click', {
    increment: -1
  }, incrementValue);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="minus" href="#">-</a>
<span id="value">0</span>
<a id="plus" href="#">+</a>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `addClass()` function?  (Or `removeClass()` or `toggleClass()`?)

Comment: Well, may be toggleClass would be better. I need value to be in black color if it's 0, red color if it's lower than 0, green if it's greater than 0. Something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are calculating just can use [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) to add/remove the CSS class based on condition.

```
var value = Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment);
valueElement.text(value).toggleClass('negative', value < 0).toggleClass('positive', value > 0);
```

```js
$(function() {

  var valueElement = $('#value');
 
  function incrementValue(e) {
    var value = Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment);
    valueElement.text(value).toggleClass('negative', value < 0).toggleClass('positive', value > 0);

    return false;
  }

  $('#plus').on('click', {
    increment: 1
  }, incrementValue);

  $('#minus').on('click', {
    increment: -1
  }, incrementValue);

});
```

```css
.positive {
  color: green 
}
.negative {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="minus" href="#">-</a>
<span id="value">0</span>
<a id="plus" href="#">+</a>
```

---

For Multiple elements

```js
$(function() {

  function incrementValue(e) {
    var valueElement = $(e.target).closest('.container').find('.value');
    
    var value = Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment);
    valueElement.text(value).toggleClass('negative', value < 0).toggleClass('positive', value > 0);

    return false;
  }

  $('.plus').on('click', {
    increment: 1
  }, incrementValue);

  $('.minus').on('click', {
    increment: -1
  }, incrementValue);

});
```

```css
.positive {
  color: green
}

.negative {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <a class="minus" href="#">-</a>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a class="minus" href="#">-</a>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
The only issue is when I increase the value to 1 and than decrease to 0 it remains green. Is there a way to leave "0" always black?

Comment: @Alexus, set default CSS rule to black and in the code snippet above

Comment: Can the code snippet be improved to work with several counters on one page? E.g. if I use classes instead of ids.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic should work.

You need to return the changed value. 
and in bind functions have a callback in which you are calling that changed function and sencond function which adds or remove class based on the new value.

```
$(function(){

var valueElement = $('#value');
function incrementValue(e){
   var val =  valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment));
    return val;
};

function triggerChange(v) {
    if(v < 0 ) {
        $('#value').addClass('<class-name>');
        //likewise remove the other class
    }
    else if (v > 0) {
        $('#value').addClass('<class-name>');
        //likewise remove other class
    }
    else {
        // remove all classes on zero
    }
};
$('#plus').bind('click', {increment: 1}, function(){
    var val = incrementValue();
    triggerChange(val);
});

$('#minus').bind('click', {increment: -1}, function(){
    var val = incrementValue();
    triggerChange(val);
});
```

});